# Two order bys then picking the last element in linq

Tags: c#, linq

A for fun problem. I normally prefer to think about enumerables using linq statements, but in this case I'm not wrapping my head around it as well. Based on what I've read I might be needing a call to ThenBy? Below is an example of what the proper foreach implementation looks like:

```
var groupByRepository = flattenedBuilds.GroupBy(x => x.Repository);
foreach (var repositoryBuilds in groupByRepository)
{
    var groupByBranch = repositoryBuilds.GroupBy(x => x.SourceBranch);
    foreach (var branchBuild in groupByBranch)
    {
        var versionsOrdered = branchBuild.OrderBy(x => x.Version);
        var firstVersion = versionsOrdered.LastOrDefault();
        yield return firstVersion;
    }
}
```

Basically it groups on repository then by branch so that I can see the latest build version for each.

Even though I don't like the SQL like version of linq that seems to be the best way to express this. This version though is missing the important LastOrDefault() call.

So the question is what would this linq (or some other linq) need to make this equivalent. A goal is readability, but in looking at my current link versus the foreach loop I'm pretty sure the foreach is winning there.

```
var result = from build in flattenedBuilds
             group build by build.Repository into groupByRepository
             from repositories in groupByRepository
             group repositories by repositories.SourceBranch into groupBySourceBranch
             from sourceBranches in groupBySourceBranch
             orderby sourceBranches.Version
             select sourceBranches;
return result;
```

Comment: That's just a question of taste.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd do something like this.  I've tried to infer the structure of your flattened data, though I'm not totally sure I've read that right... but I think your `flattenedBuilds` is a list of items represented by this class:

```
class FlattenedBuild
{
    public string Branch { get; set; }
    public string Repository { get; set; }
    public int Version { get; set; }
}
```

So I've written this to build some sample data (just as a `List` in my case)

```
static FlattenedBuild B(string repo, string branch, int version)
{
    return new FlattenedBuild 
    { 
       Branch = branch, 
       Repository = repo, 
       Version = version 
    };
}

...

var flattenedBuilds = new List<FlattenedBuild>()
{
   B("Project X", "master",1),
   B("Project X", "master",2),
   B("Project X", "master",3),
   B("Project X", "develop",2),
   B("Project X", "develop",8),
   B("Project Y", "master",1),
   B("Project Y", "feature_main",1),
   B("Project Y", "develop",4),
   B("Project Y", "develop",6),
   B("Project Y", "develop",12)
};
```

Then the actual LINQ stuff simply groups by all unique combinations of Repository and Branch, then gets the highest build no. for each unique combination:

```
var result = flattenedBuilds
    .GroupBy(b => new { b.Repository, b.Branch })
    .Select(g => new
    {
       g.Key.Repository,
       g.Key.Branch,
       LastBuild = g.OrderByDescending(v => v.Version).FirstOrDefault()?.Version
    });
```

Then simply this to check the results:

```
 foreach (var x in result)
 {
    Console.WriteLine($"last build for {x.Repository}/{x.Branch} was {x.LastBuild}");
 }
```

which outputs this:

```
last build for Project X/master was 3
last build for Project X/develop was 8
last build for Project Y/master was 1
last build for Project Y/feature_main was 1
last build for Project Y/develop was 12
```

Which I *think* is what you're after?

Comment: Thank you, your answer was most helpful to me in learning. GroupBy(b => new { b.Repository, b.Branch }) was new to me pretty neat.

Comment: You're welcome :).  It's just creating a new *anonymous type* in the same way as the `new{...}` in the `Select()` method does.  In case you haven't guessed, I do this sort of stuff *a lot* these days...

Answer (score 0):

A more or less straightforward translation of your `foreach` code yields:

```
var ans = flattenedBuilds.GroupBy(b => b.Repository)
                         .SelectMany(b_rg => b_rg.GroupBy(b => b.SourceBranch)
                                                 .Select(b_r_sbg => b_r_sbg.OrderByDescending(x => x.Version).First())
                         );
```

I prefer `OrderByDescending`/`First` over `OrderBy`/`Last` as it is more efficient since `First` returns immediately. Also, `GroupBy` will only create groups containing at least one member, so `FirstOrDefault` isn't needed - you know there is at least one.